# when running 'rake db:setup' getting deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

hope someone can help me here:
I have 
  *  changed the database in my application from sqlit3 to postgresql, 
  *  replaced the gemfile to gem 'pg', 
  *  update database.yml

all this, in order to be able to deploy to heroku.

when I run

```
rake db:setup
```

I am getting these errors:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Single arity template handlers are deprecated. Template handlers must
now accept two parameters, the view object and the source for the view object.
Change:
  >> Coffee::Rails::TemplateHandler.call(template)
To:
  >> Coffee::Rails::TemplateHandler.call(template, source)
```

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Couldn't create 'school-grades-project' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I read that jbuilder should take care on the issue, so I upgraded jbuilder, but still the problem remains.

would appreciate some help here.
thanks,

Comment: when upgrading the  coffee-rails gem to a higher version (5.0.0), the first warning was eliminated. However, still have the problem that it cannot connect to the server

Comment: Your postgresql instance isn't listening to 5432. Are you sure it's running?

Comment: now, I am getting this error message:                                           
         PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: And what's the answer to the question in the error message and in [Josh Brody's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61859824/when-running-rake-dbsetup-getting-deprecation-warning#comment109413393_61859824)?

Comment: yes, postgresql is running...

Answer (score 1):

Here I have a quick solution.

This issue came into existence after updating the application to rails 6.x, To resolve it update the following gems:

```
Updating coffee-rails to 5.0.0 fixed this for me
```

Then run the bundle update and start the application server solved the warning issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to diagnose this because you didn't specify the version of Rails that you're using or the contents of your `database.yml` file. But assuming it's a recent Rails version with support for database URLs it should work by following the descriptions in the [Getting started guide for Rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails6#add-the-pg-gem).

```
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
```

Did you uncomment the `production` settings?